# FullText index on unique clustered index with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to create a full text index on a multiple column clustered index?

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_ContactsView
    ON ContactsView (ContactId,CeId,CpId);
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.ContactsView
 (Name,Email,PhoneNumber) KEY INDEX idx_ContactsView
 ON ContactsCatalog;  

 ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON ContactsView SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

FOR SQL-SERVER, AZURE SQL

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Surely you received the error that states your full-text search key must be a single column, yes? I don't think this is possible, but maybe someone has an interesting workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If your index is not unique, not non-nullable, and not single-column, it cannot be used for fulltext indexing.

You may get the following error message from the database engine if you try to define a full text search key with a composite clustered index/primary key.

> "PK_MESSAGES_A87A0A9A1EA32A6C is not a valid index to enforce a
>   full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique,
>   non-nullable, single-column index which is not offline, is not defined
>   on a non-deterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column, does
>   not have a filter, and has maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another
>   index for the full-text key."